Could not find Nx modules in this workspace while using Heroku deployment for NestJS app
I have an Nx workspace (v. 20.1) with a NestJS app. Locally, everything works fine, nx build, etc. But when running CI on Heroku, I get this error:
NX   Could not find Nx modules in this workspace.
My package.json:
...
"scripts": {
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install && npm run build:prod",
    "build:prod": "nx build my-node-app --configuration production",
...
}
...


So, after many tries, I've found the issue which was not using "heroku-postbuild" script for nx build. It looks like prebuild doesn't wait for npm install, and nx is unavailable.
Here is the working package.json:
...
"scripts": {
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "nx build my-node-app --configuration production",
    "start": "node dist/apps/my-node-app/main.js",
    "build:prod": "nx build my-node-app --configuration production"
  },
...

